# How to add search into action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, searchview, android-search

Know anyone how can I add the **searchview** in **action bar** on Android?
I've try a lot of example and I've search on google so much time but I don't find the solution for my problem... I've find how to put the search into action bar but after that I can't use my search... I can just open it.

Here it's the activity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {


    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;
    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setCustomView(mSearchView);
        mSearchView.setQuery("", true);
        mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
        mSearchView.setIconified(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here it's my [result](http://imgur.com/7v1tAJF) with **search bar** and **action bar** as individual. 
So if anyone knows how can I solve that problem please show me, I will be very gratitude for how can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the onCreateOptionsMenu method to set up your action bar with search. This code snippet should help you.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_list, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                //Fetch the data remotely
                FetchData(query);

                //Reset the SearchView
                searchView.clearFocus();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                searchItem.collapseActionView();

                //Set Activity title to search query
                MainActivity.this.setTitle(query);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you change this code to work for me? Because I've try to use it and I have so many errors... for example my searchView will be all time NULL. Or  FetchData(query) give me error, and I don't use anyway query... I have just one String with name in it. If you can do that for me I will be very gratitude.

Comment: And yes, I've change to use my R.id on searchItem, I don't let yours